# how to update laptop firmware on linux

Tags: bios, firmware

Lenovo does not seem to provide laptop firmware updates for linux. Laptops tend to lack a dvd drive lately. How do I update under Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: lately I've been using [VENTOY](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) to boot from ISOs easily.

Here's what a colleague shared recently. Thought it might be useful to a wider audience. Marking as a community wiki as I don't share credit for it. Procedure might work for other laptop makes I guess.

- Visit the driver matrix for your T460p on support.lenovo.com and download the image of the "BIOS Update CD for Windows 10". (I ended up getting the version for dos But I don't think it really matters)
- If not already installed, install genisoimage and [geteltorito](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/rpms/geteltorito/):

  - `yum install genisoimage geteltorito`
- Extract the El Torito boot-image from the downloaded *.iso-file,

  - in my case that is `r07uj12wd.iso`:
  - `geteltorito -o bios.img r07uj12wd.iso`
  - Find out the block device name of your USB flash drive: `lsblk` (e.g. `/dev/sdb`)
- Write the extracted image to an USB stick. In my case it is the USB (I had a old 1G laying around I used) stick is attached as `/dev/sdb`:

  - `dd if=bios.img of=/dev/sdX bs=1M status=progress ; sync`
  - Boot from the USB stick and follow BIOS upgrade instructions

I did this on my t420s And it worked with out a problem

**Attention:** the above `dd` command is very dangerous as you can wipe out important data in case you choose the wrong device name. That's why I've put `X` in place of letter there - to avoid careless copy/paste troubles. Proceed with care!